# Highlight path in d3 tree is not working in IE

Tags: d3.js

I created tree layout as in JSFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/oo66o0q0/15/.
Requirement is path should highlighted in red and with extra width when user click on node's right click menu "Highlight Route" option.
This is working in chrome correctly but in IE highlighted route color becomes black.
If I remove markers then it works in IE as well.
How to resolve this issue in IE but not removing markers?

```
    function treeInitialize(graphData){

    diagramLayout = d3.select("#diagramLayout")
                        .attr("id", "diagramLayout")//set id
                        .attr("width", width)//set width
                        .attr("height", height)//set height
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 20 + "," + 20 + ")")  

    markerRefx = 40;

    var data2 = graphData.links.filter(function(l){ 
        if(l.target == undefined && l.source == undefined){
            return false;   
        }else{
            return true;
        }
        });
    data2.push(JSON.parse('{"target":"glossforArrow","source":""}'))

    var treeData = d3.stratify().id(function(d){ return d.target; }).parentId(function(d) {
                        return d.source;    
                    })(data2)

    nodes = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {return d.children;});

    var levelWidth = [1];
    var childCount = function(level, n) {

       if(n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
         if(levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);

         levelWidth[level+1] += n.children.length;
         n.children.forEach(function(d) {
           childCount(level + 1, d);
         });
       }
     };
    childCount(0, nodes);    
    newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 100;     
    var tree = d3.tree().size([height, width])   

    tree.size([newHeight,height/2]); 

    tree.separation(function (a, b) {
                return a.parent == b.parent ? 50 : 100;
            });                     
    nodes = tree(nodes);    
    treeLayout(nodes);

                function treeLayout(nodes){ 

                var node = diagramLayout.selectAll(".node");
                node = node.data(nodes.descendants());

                var link = diagramLayout.selectAll(".link")
      .data(nodes.descendants().slice(1))
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "#000")
      .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", "0.3")
      .attr("d",connector)

        nodes.descendants().slice(1).forEach(function(d) { 

                    var mark = diagramLayout.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")//
                        .data(["start"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
                        .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
                        .attr("id", String)
                        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
                        .attr("refX", -markerRefx)
                        .attr("refY", 0)
                        .attr("markerWidth", 5)
                        .attr("markerHeight", 5)
                        .attr("orient", "auto")
                        .attr("stroke", "#000")
                        .attr("fill", "#000")
                        .append("svg:path")
                        .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5")
                        .style("stroke-width", "0.3px")
          .attr("transform","rotate(180,5, 0)");

                }); 

      link.attr("marker-start", "url(#start)")




                var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("height", nodeHeight)
                .attr("width", nodeWidth)
                    nodeEnter.attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + project(d.x, d.y) + ")"; 
                    }).on('contextmenu', menuCall); 


                var nodeIcon =   nodeEnter.append("rect")   
                .attr("class", "rect")
                .attr("x", -20)
                .attr("y", -20)
                .attr("rx", 10)
                .attr("width", 40)
                .attr("height", 40)
                .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(2); }) 
                .attr("stroke-opacity", "0.3")
                .attr("stroke", "#000" )
                .attr("fill", "blue" )  


                //wrap(nodeText, 8) 
            }

    }

    function connector(d) {
        return "M" + project(d.x, d.y)
                + "C" + project(d.x, (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2)
                + " " + project(d.parent.x, (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2)
                + " " + project(d.parent.x, d.parent.y);
    }

    function project(x, y) {

        return [x,y];
    }

    function menuCall(di,i) {
    var nodeClicked = d3.select(this);
    var menuitems = ["Highlight route"];

    d3.selectAll('.context-menu').data([1])
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'context-menu');
      // close menu
    d3.select('body').on('click.context-menu', function() {
        d3.select('.context-menu').style('display', 'none');
      });
      // this gets executed when a contextmenu event occurs
    d3.selectAll('.context-menu')
        .html('')
        .append('ul')
        .selectAll('li')
            .data(menuitems).enter()
            .append('li')

        .on('click' , function(d) {
    //  d3.select('.context-menu').style('display', 'none');        
     if(d=="Highlight route"){
    var id = nodeClicked.datum().data.id;
                        var node = diagramLayout.selectAll(".node");
                        var link = diagramLayout.selectAll(".link");

                        link.style("stroke","black").style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
                        var linkSelected =  link.filter(function (d, i) { 
              console.log(d.data.id)
              console.log(id)
              return d.data.id === id;});
                        linkSelected.style("stroke", "red").style("stroke-width", "5px");

                }
            d3.select('.context-menu').style('display', 'none');
                 }).text(function(di) { return di; });

            d3.select('.context-menu').style('display', 'none');
              // show the context menu
            d3.select('.context-menu')
                .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 2) + 'px')
                .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 2) + 'px')
                .style('display', 'block');
            d3.event.preventDefault();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in IE.  If you inspect the DOM after you apply the highlight, IE reports that the inline style has overridden the sheet style (as it should), but the path does not update:

[image]

The only fix I can think us is to remove the sheet stroke style on class link

```
.link {
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}
```

And just apply all the styles in-line.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oo66o0q0/17/).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering question but this type of arrows are looking different than my projects requirement?

Comment: @user6821214, I don't understand your comment.  Is that a question for me?  What's "your requirement"?  You asked why the highlight wasn't red under IE, that's the question I answered.